# Uniform stochastic process on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Are there known examples (and do they exist at all) of a stochastic process $X$ with a.s. continuous trajectories such that $X_t$ is uniformly distributed on an $\mathbb R^n$ ball around origin with a radius of $t$?

Comment: First pick $\beta$ to be uniformly distributed in the unit ball. Then let $X_t =t\beta$. The  trajectories $t\mapsto X_t = t\beta$ are continuous, but not very interesting.

Comment: How is that continuous? I guess you would have to interpolate